# prove that there exist $x_1\neq x_2, x_1,x_2\in [0,1]$ so that $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)dx = (x_1-x_2)^{2002}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, inequality

> Let $f : [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function so that $0 < |\int_0^1 f(x)dx| \leq 1$. Prove that there exist $x_1\neq x_2, x_1,x_2\in [0,1]$ so that $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)dx = (x_1-x_2)^{2002}$.

Let $F : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt.$ Note that if we have $|F(b)-F(a)| \ge |b-a|^{2002}$ for all $a\neq b\in [0,1],$ then we can just choose $x_1 = a, x_2 = b$ or vice versa (so that the sign of $F(x_2)-F(x_1)$ is positive) so that $1\ge |F(1)-F(0)| \ge 1.$ If $|F(b)-F(a)|\leq |b-a|^{2002}$ for all $b\neq a$ in $[0,1]$, then for an arbitrary $a\in [0,1],$ letting $b\to a,$ we get that $|F'(a)| \leq \lim\limits_{b\to a} |b-a|^{2001} = 0$ and hence $F'(a) = 0$ for all a. Hence $F$ is constant, contradicting $0 < |F(1)-F(0)|.$ Thus there exist $a,b,c,d\in [0,1]$ with $|F(b)-F(a)| < |b-a|^{2002}$ and $|F(d)-F(c)| > |d-c|^{2002}$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Perhaps using the Intermediate Value Theorem might be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the IVT is useful here: Wlog we can assume $a < b$ and $c < d$, now define

$$
g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}\\
t \mapsto |F(ta+(1-t)c) - F(tb+(1-t)d)| - |t(a-b) + (1-t)(c-d)|^{2002}
$$

which is continuous and satisfies $g(1) < 0 < g(0)$, so by the IVT there must be some $s \in (0, 1)$ such that $g(s) = 0$. Therefore we get

\begin{align*}
 |F(sa+(1-s)c) - F(sb+(1-s)d)| &= |s(a-b) + (1-s)(c-d)|^{2002} \\
&= |sa + (1-s)c -(sb + (1-s)d)|^{2002},
\end{align*}
so either

$$
 F(sa+(1-s)c) - F(sb+(1-s)d) = (sa + (1-s)c -(sb + (1-s)d))^{2002}
$$

or
$$
F(sb+(1-s)d) - F(sa+(1-s)c) = (sb + (1-s)d -(sa + (1-s)c))^{2002}
$$

and we just have to verify that those are distinct points, but since we assumed $ a < b, c < d$ we also get

$$sa + (1-s)c < sb + (1-s)d,$$

so they are indeed distinct.